# Receiving data message from Kannel?

Tags: android, smsmanager, receiver, kannel

I want to send and receive DataMessage (android phone - kannel | kannel - android phone), i'm using sendDataMessage (SmsManager Android), and i'm abale to send a text message from kannel to android phone using this `http://smsbox.host.name:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=foo&password=bar&to=0123456&text=Hello+world` but i want to receive a data message from Kannel, it's possible from Kannel?

this is configuration in manifest to receive a dataMessage

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:port="8901" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: so, arent you receiving sms ?

Comment: @Lucifer i'm reciving a textMessage, but i want to receive a dataMessage (binary SMS) using this on manifest <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />

Comment: Have you tried setting host as well? `<data android:scheme ="sms" android:host="*" android:port="8901`